# Hi. Im trying to create a code to remove a watermark of an image using scilab. Is this code correct? cause it has some errors

Tags: scilab

```
image = imread('watermarkimage2.jpg');

mask = imread('ig2.png');
opacity = 0.65;
FG = 0.81; 

R = im2double(image);
mask = im2double(mask);
alpha = mask*opacity;
BG = (R-FG.*alpha)./(1-alpha);

BG = BG.*mask + im2double(image).*(1-mask);

imshow(BG,'border','tight')`
```

it says Inconsistent row/column dimensions in this part:  BG = (R-FG.*alpha)./(1-alpha);

I tried removing "." but it still has your text errors. anyone have ideas on what's wrong?`your text`

Comment: Check the size of `alpha` and `R`, they likely differ.